# Generate infinite stream of letter combinations while conserving memory?

Tags: python, string, memory, memory-management, python-itertools

I am attempting to write a program that generates strings one by one in different combinations (starting at "a" and ending at "zzzzzz*") and converts the string into hashes, then checks the hash for comparison against another hash. I am currently using `itertools` for the task, however it seems that it generates a rather large list of strings and stores them all in memory at once before processing.

When running the below code for around 5 minutes in the command line, the commandline itself takes up over 4GB of memory, which I believe can be greatly slimmed down.

What I would like to do is 1) generate each string one at a time rather than in an array, and 2) manage memory in such a way in that after I use that string, it is removed from memory, either manually or through the garbage collector. How can I accomplish this?

```
#!/bin/env/python
import itertools
import string
import hashlib

def stringGen(charset, maxlength):
    return (''.join(candidate)
        for candidate in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.product(charset, repeat=i)
        for i in range(1, maxlength + 1)))
i=0        
for attempt in stringGen(string.ascii_lowercase, 10):
    i+=1
    aHash = hashlib.sha256(attempt).hexdigest()
    print attempt
    print aHash + " " + str(i) + "\n"
    if aHash == hashlib.sha256("longword").hexdigest():
        print "matched" 
        break
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for generator expressions.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503388/prevent-memory-error-in-itertools-permutation for example.

Comment: `itertools` are *"Functions creating iterators for efficient looping"* - are you *sure* they are storing things all in memory? We can't tell because you haven't shown any code.

Comment: This might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568564/what-is-taking-up-the-memory-in-this-for-loop

Comment: Write each string as a line in a file rather than in an array. If it is in an array, it's in memory.

Comment: Okay I have uploaded my code and modified the text a bit. Thank you for the incredibly quick comments on this. Hopefully that helps.

I am actually unclear if the memory being eaten is from itertools. What I do know is that running this for 5 minutes eats up 4GB of ram coming from the terminal process.

Comment: Have you perhaps disabled garbage collection somehow?  When I run that script the memory footprint is tiny.

Comment: I've never intentionally disabled it, but its possible I guess. Are you checking the memory of python or the commandline running the python?

Comment: I'm using `top`.  So checking memory of everything, really.  And I'll note as-written, your program uses generators properly, so all the strings are generated on the fly.  The problem has to be elsewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: LINQ capable class supporting simultaneously laziness and fluent design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154269/python-linq-capable-class-supporting-simultaneously-laziness-and-fluent-design)