# Python: LINQ capable class supporting simultaneously laziness and fluent design

Tags: python, linq, iterator, generator

How to create an Python class which would be a iterable wrapper with LINQ-like methods (select, where, orderby, etc.) without using extension methods or monkey patching.
?

That is this LinqCapable class would be capable to return its own type when it is relevant (i.e. fluent design) and support lazy evaluation.

I'm just looking here for a snippet as a starting point.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot chain"? You simply need to return a new LinqCapable object that encapsulates the above filtered enumerator... What else is missing?

Comment: Since you're doing a for loop, I can't see the lazy behavior that you claim instead. The asq on github achieves laziness by an ifilter for the where: it looks correct, at first sight. Finally notice that the Linq Queryable is lazy, not the IEnumerable...

Comment: @Machine Learning back in C# var filtered = source.where(Whathever); filtered is not evaluated at that point until we start to write something like var actualFilteredSource = filtered.ToArray(); cause the evaluation is require to generate the collection involved by the ToArray extension method.

Comment: filtered is not evaluated *iff* source is IQueryable. How to do that? I'd say that Linq is doing that by resorting to AST that would be too complex to implement anew. In Python *afaik* you could use the ifilter as asq does. More generally I don't understand what you don't like in the asq implementation: you are complaining about extensions, but that's exactly what linq methods are :-)

Comment: AFAIK it does use AST (might worth to have a look at MS repos on Github since they are publicly available).
Why bothering myself? 
Just for sake of reinventing the wheel without extension methods :)
One more thing, I don't dislike asq just wanted to do things on my own, thought they would be some nasty ways to make it.

Comment: I don't need to be taught about linq, I'm only trying to help you since your question looks unclear: you speak about laziness, but you mention IEnumerable and "for loops" that are not lazy. In your comment you reply about "MS github", while I'm suggesting that in Python there is not such a feature to translate AST into expression at runtime and manipulate them as well... Unless you edit your question and you better define the scope, the code that you're showing now doesn't fall even close to compare to those methods...

Comment: @MachineLearning 1]Don't get me wrong I'm not trying to teach you anything, I'm not really in position for that. 2] I'm not pretending that Python has the same features as C# (otherwise I would suspect that the vast majority of the programming languages are pretty much the same which does not seem to be the cas). 3]I rephrased the whole question to make it short and straight to the point 4] Thanks for your answer =]

Comment: @MachineLearning about my initial question, yes the laziness in the snippet was not achieved and this was my point. The phrasing was really awkward saying the opposite didn't help to clearly express my intent, that's for sure. My bad didn't realized it until you mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to just return a generator for the implemented linq methods, you need to have it return an instance of the wrapper to be able to chain additional calls.

You can create a metaclass which can rewrap the linq implementations.  So with this, you can just implement the methods you want to support and use some special decorators to ensure it remains chainable.

```
def linq(iterable):
    from functools import wraps
    def as_enumerable(f):
        f._enumerable = True
        return f
    class EnumerableMeta(type):
        def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace):
            cls = type.__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace)
            def to_enumerable(f):
                @wraps(f)
                def _f(self, *args, **kwargs):
                    return cls(lambda: f(self, *args, **kwargs))
                return _f
            for n, f in namespace.items():
                if hasattr(f, '_enumerable'):
                    setattr(cls, n, to_enumerable(f))
            return cls
    class Enumerable(metaclass=EnumerableMeta):
        def __init__(self, _iterable):
            self._iterable = _iterable
        def __iter__(self):
            return iter(self._iterable())
        @as_enumerable
        def intersect(self, second):
            yield from set(self._iterable()).intersection(second)
        @as_enumerable
        def select(self, selector):
            yield from map(selector, self._iterable())
        @as_enumerable
        def union(self, second):
            yield from set(self._iterable()).union(second)
        @as_enumerable
        def where(self, predicate):
            yield from filter(predicate, self._iterable())
        @as_enumerable
        def skip(self, count):
            yield from (x for x, i in enumerate(self._iterable()) if i >= count)
        @as_enumerable
        def skip_while(self, predicate):
            it = iter(self._iterable())
            for x in it:
                if not predicate(x):
                    yield x
                    break
            yield from it
        @as_enumerable
        def take(self, count):
            yield from (x for x, i in enumerate(self._iterable()) if i < count)
        @as_enumerable
        def take_while(self, predicate):
            for x in self._iterable():
                if not predicate(x): break
                yield x
        @as_enumerable
        def zip(self, second, result_selector=lambda a, b: (a, b)):
            yield from map(lambda x: result_selector(*x), zip(self._iterable(), second))
        def single(self, predicate=lambda _: True):
            has_result = False
            for x in self._iterable():
                if predicate(x):
                    if has_result:
                        raise TypeError('sequence contains more elements')
                    value = x
                    has_result = True
            if not has_result:
                raise TypeError('sequence contains no elements')
            return value

        def sum(self, selector=lambda x: x):
            return sum(map(selector, self._iterable()))
        def to_dict(self, key_selector, element_selector=lambda x: x):
            return {
                (key_selector(x), element_selector(x))
                for x in self._iterable()
            }
        def to_list(self):
            return list(self._iterable())
    return Enumerable(lambda: iterable)
```

So you'd be able to do things like this with any iterable sequence as you might do it in C#.

```
# save a linq query
query = linq(range(100))

# even numbers as strings
evenstrs = query.where(lambda i: i%2 == 0).select(str)

# build a different result using the same query instances
odds = query.where(lambda i: i%2 != 0)
smallnums = query.where(lambda i: i < 50)
```

```
# dynamically build a query
query = linq(some_list_of_objects)

if some_condition:
    query = query.where(some_predicate)

if some_other_condition:
    query = query.where(some_other_predicate)

result = query.to_list()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return a "Linq capable class" to achieve chaining and furthermore your implementation  is not lazy: look at asq where method: it is based on the I filter and it appears correct...
Anyway, here it is a very basic implementation based on my understanding of your question and comments

```
class LinqCapable(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        self._iterable = iterable
        self._predicates = []
    def where(self, predicate):
        chain = LinqCapable(self._iterable)
        chain._predicates = self._predicates
        chain._predicates.append(predicate)
        return chain
    def toArray(self):
        for item in self._iterable:
          isOk = True
          for predicate in self._predicates:
            if (not predicate(item)):
                isOk = False
                break

          if (isOk):
              yield item
```

### Usage

```
test = LinqCapable([1,2,3])
def pred1(l: int) -> bool:
   return l>1
chain1 = test.where(pred1)
def pred2(l: int) -> bool:
   return l<3
chain2 = chain1.where(pred2)
list(chain2.toArray())
```

### Edit (adding also a select method)

I've added also a simple select method.
The objective here is to aggregate predicates and selectors when possible, to avoid inefficient nested loops.

```
class LinqCapable(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable=None, predicates = [],  selectors = [],  tree=None):
        self._iterable =  iterable
        self._predicates = list(predicates)
        self._selectors = list(selectors)
        self._tree = tree
    def select(self,  selector):
        if (len(self._predicates) == 0):
            chain = LinqCapable(self._iterable,  [], self._selectors,  self._tree)
            chain._selectors.append(selector) 
        else:
            chain = LinqCapable(None,  [],  [])
            if (len(self._selectors) == 0):
                chain._tree = LinqCapable(self._iterable,  self._predicates,  [],  self._tree)
            else:
                chain._tree = self
            chain._selectors.append(selector) 
        return chain
    def where(self, predicate):
        chain = LinqCapable(self._iterable,  self._predicates,  self._selectors,  self._tree)
        chain._predicates.append(predicate)
        return chain
    def enumerate(self):
        if  (self._tree != None):
            self._iterable = list(self._tree.enumerate())
        return self._cycle()
    def _cycle(self):
        for item in self._iterable:
          for selector in self._selectors:
            item = selector(item)
          isOk = True
          for predicate in self._predicates:
            if (not predicate(item)):
                isOk = False
                break
          if (isOk):
              yield item
```

so an example would be

```
test = LinqCapable([1,2, 20,200, 300])
def pred1(l: int) -> bool:
   return l>1
chain1 = test.where(pred1)
def pred2(l: int) -> bool:
   return l<300
def sel1(l: int) -> str:
   return str(l)
def sel2(l: str) -> str:
   return '<' + l + '>'
def pred3(l: str) -> bool:
   return len(l) > 3
def sel3(l: str) -> str:
   return l[1:-1]
def sel4(l: str) -> int:
   return int(l)
chain2 = chain1.where(pred2).select(sel1).select(sel2).where(pred3).select(sel3).select(sel4)
print(list(chain2.enumerate()))
```

Comment: Thanks for nice feedback :-) I've also added a simple select method now...

Comment: I see you already noticed that the first version copies the predicates and other data by reference, so creating a `where` query (for example) modifies the original structure as well. Since the original code is still in your post, I'm pointing this out to save readers a bit of trouble if they don't realize you actually rewrote the functions from the upper code block.

Comment: fixed a bug with a more complex example

Comment: @piojo Correct, I'll reinforce this concept possibly later, thanks